# ember build is not setting the correct rootUrl

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Messing around with deploying, and I'm going to need to put the app outside the root url of the server. Based on [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3861) answer all I need to do is change the environment.js file to look like this.

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        modulePrefix: 'ember-drupal',
        environment: environment,
        rootURL: '/',
        locationType: 'auto'
    };

    if (environment === 'production') {
        ENV.rootUrl = '/myApp/';
        ENV.locationType = 'hash';
    }
    return ENV;
};
```

So when I run

```
ember build --environment=production
```

I expect it to set the rootUrl to be /myApp/, yet when I load up localhost/myApp/ it gives me 404 saying that it's still looking for /assets/ instead of /myApp/assets.

Two interesting notes.

1. If I change the default rootUrl to /myApp/, it works.
2. The source code has a meta tag called "ember-drupal/config/environment". The content of the meta tag is json of my environment variables.

The 'ember build' command spits out this:

```
{
"modulePrefix":"ember-drupal",
"environment":"development",
"rootURL":"/",
"locationType":"auto",
"exportApplicationGlobal":true
}
```

And the 'ember build --environment=production' spits out this:

```
{
"modulePrefix":"ember-drupal",
"environment":"production",
"rootURL":"/",
"locationType":"hash",
"rootUrl":"/myApp/",
"exportApplicationGlobal":false
}
```

So it's setting the locationType correctly, but setting the rootUrl twice.

Answer (score 0):

A freaking capitalization error..... rootUrl vs rootURL. It took me all the way of typing this out to find it.